# Anchoring an item in place for vertical scrolling but not horizontal

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a menu that is contained in a div with the class float. float is given below:

```
.float {
display:block; 
position:fixed; 
top: 20px;
left: 0px;
z-index: 1999999999;
}
* html .float {position:absolute;}
```

The above css class makes it so that the menu stays in place regardless of how the user scrolls (the *html is for internet explorer). However, I need to make it so that it only stays in place when the user scrolls vertically. It should move left to right if the user scrolls left or right. I can't seem to find any css to allow for this, and any javascript I run into is choppy in adjusting the item. The javascript below works but I'd like something a bit smoother if possible. I have the body tag set to onload="scrolladj()" with scrolladj() being written out below:

```
function scrolladj()
{

    if(brow == 'Microsoft Internet Explorer')
    {

        o = document.documentElement.scrollLeft;

    }
    else
    {

        o = window.pageXOffset;

    }

    $('main_menu').style.left = (20-o)+'px';


}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I think that behaviour is *way* outside the current bounds of CSS (sadly). It's probably do-able with JavaScript, though.

Comment: Yea, it's getting to be a real issue :/ I'm amazed how underdeveloped browsers really are. Hopefully someone has a way to do this.

Comment: Why do you have horizontal scrolling on the page? Do you mean the case where the browser window width is smaller than the webpage width?

Comment: Yes. I have the site created to fit well into 1024x768 screens (majority of my target audience are using higher resolutions than this). However, I want to stay prepared for those that may decrease the size of the browser window, lower resolutions, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code works for FF and Chrome

```
<HTML>
 <HEAD>
    <style>
        .float {
    display:block; 
    position:fixed; 
    top: 20px;
    left: 0px;
    z-index: 1999999999;
    }


    </style>
  <script>
    function x()
    {
        if(document.body.offsetLeft != document.body.scrollLeft)
            document.getElementById('fd').style.position='absolute';
        else
            document.getElementById('fd').style.position='fixed';
    }
  </script>
 </HEAD>

 <BODY onscroll="x();">
    <div class="float" id="fd">
        sdkjfkljfs
    </div>
  <div style="overflow: auto; width: 2000px; height: 1000px" >
  </div>
 </BODY>
</HTML>
```